# Standard way of prompting user to select folder to write a file to?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My goal is to have a button that, when clicked, pops open a 'Select Folder' window. I'd like to work with the path they selected afterwards.

I did a bit of reading around on this and I kept coming up with the FolderBrowserDialog class from Windows.Forms. Is this still the accepted means of capturing the path for ASP.NET AJAX? If so... will this work on non-windows computers?

Thanks

Comment: So you want to do this in a web browser? You are aware of all the security restrictions concerning local file system access, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't mix use `FolderBrowserDialog` on ASP.NET.

If you want them to browse their computer for a folder name, I'm sorry but that's not possible for security reasons.

If you want them to browse a folder on your server, you will have to design a system that will allow them to do that.

Comment: Ahh, I had not that about the security issues behind this. Yeah, completely my bad, haha. Should just have them download the file!